# Enter user location on Windows Phone 8 Maps

Tags: windows-phone-8, maps, here-api

Making a map application on Windows Phone 8. Thanks to a the tutorials on MSDN I can automatically find the users location and, if services are turned off, default to a city.

I would also like to let the user specify their location using a street name or post code. The user will input this into a text box. My question is how do I change thee maps centre to an inputted postcode or street name?

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the GPS coordinates for the address and then center the map to this coordinates. Bing API provides reverse geocoding.

Comment: Another advantage of this - i.e. using the [GeocodeQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.maps.services.geocodequery(v=vs.105).aspx) class is that the initial look up will be on the *device*. This eliminates the need to be connected online. Furthermore you'll be using the SDK integrated with the map, and therefore the same data set

Answer (score 0):

google geocoding API

you can send a Geocoding request and you will get a response as JSON/XML format.
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/?csw=1#GeocodingResponses